# Fetching data in Remix Run components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

I have a basic web app using the Remix Run Blues stack that I'm working on which includes a search bar in the header, and I want to query the database every time someone types in the search input. The header, and the search bar could be their own 'components' (`/app/components/`?).

It's my understanding that you can only use Remix `loaders` on routes (e.g. `/app/routes/`). So my question is how am I supposed to structure my app in a way that I can keep my UI components decoupled (e.g. the search component in its own file, included in a header component) but also fetch data on every `onChange` event by utilising the `loaders`?

I've read the following docs but it's still not entirely clear to me:

- https://remix.run/docs/en/main/guides/routing
- https://remix.run/docs/en/main/guides/resource-routes

Thanks.

Comment: Here's an article talking about "full-stack" components. UI Component + Resource Route. https://www.epicweb.dev/full-stack-components

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done without a resource route, utilizing normal loaders. Basically you'll invoke a url change (search parameters of the url) when the input on the textbox changes.

When the url changes, this will invoke your loader. You can then inside your loader, access the search params inside your request object, and query your data accordingly.

The below code should give you an idea on how this can be done.

```
const submitter = useSubmit();

...

<input type="text" onChange={(e) => {
 const searchValue = e.currentTarget.value;

 const formData = new FormData();
 formData.set('search', searchValue);
 submitter(formData, { replace: true });

}}/>
```